# how to get recently added records for each person in django query

Tags: python, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, django-class-based-views

I need to get recently added records for each person. I have a table like below

```
  id     person     date     task
   1      xxx    2015-11-18    3
   2      yyy    2015-11-17    2
   3      yyy    2015-11-19    2
   4      xxx    2015-11-30    1
```

I would like to get a output like this in queryset

```
   id     person     date     task
    3      yyy    2015-11-19    2
    4      xxx    2015-11-30    1
```

each person have two records. but i need to get recently added records for that each person in django queryset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is about the right query, but you have to watch the joined use of *order_by* and *distinct* as explained in the *doc*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

```
Record.objects.order_by('person', '-date').distinct('person')
```

Comment: Am not mention about the duplicate. I want to get it by date which is recently added for each person.

Comment: But i think answer from @schwobaseggl should do the job

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can use

[`Window Function:over()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
   SELECT id
        ,person
        ,dte
        ,task
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY person ORDER BY dte DESC
                ) rn
        FROM rt
        ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
```

or

[`DISTINCT Clause`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (person) id
    ,person
    ,dte
    ,task
FROM rt
ORDER BY person
    ,dte DESC
```

---

[`SQLFIDDLE-DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/43204/1)

Comment: I would like to get  using django ORM query.

Comment: @PythonTeam I don't know `django` and `pyhton` but I know PostgreSQL that's why I post this answer because it's tagged under PostgreSQL

Comment: Okay thanks.. But i want to know it using django ORM Query